# Is it not possible to use Windows Bash as shell in Emacs for ssh etc?

Tags: windows, bash, emacs

I tried but get error: Process shell exited abnormally with code 255.
Mainly want this for SSH, and avoid Cygwin or plink/Putty.

I have this in config:

```
(setq explicit-shell-file-name "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe")
(setq explicit-bash.exe-args '("--noediting" "--login" "-i"))
(setenv "SHELL" shell-file-name)
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-strip-ctrl-m)
```

Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind Bash on Ubuntu on Windows [is a **beta** technology](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about).  According to [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/10/19/windows-and-ubuntu-interoperability/) I/O redirection between Windows and Linux software will be "coming soon", that was about four months ago so perhaps it is already available in a Windows Insider build.

Answer (score 1):

I use Bash for Windows with the latest Windows Creator's Update and Ubuntu 16.04 they have included. It runs quite well on Visual Studio Code and Cmder (a shell app like MobaXTerm etc). I also use ZSH instead of Bash (with oh-my-zsh and powerline9k) but i had some adjustments to do (and, it takes time to load, but i've read somewhere that Microsoft is working to fix this slow issue).
To be honest, it's a good way to replace Putty, but it has to grow a little. There's a lot of network tools that can't work on WSL for example.

I know the pain to prepare a Cygwin or use Putty, but you can take a look on MobaXterm, a really good ssh client that includes a package manager to allow you to do a lot of things from your Windows. I don't know if they use Cygwin like in the past ... But it's a ready-to-use solution with local bash shell.

To finish this and maybe help you, here is my startup line to run WSL / Bash for Windows in Cmder: `bash -l -i -cur_console:p -c zsh`. If you need any more information just ask :).